# Concatenation error with equal sign VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code where `ttlMtrs` is an integer < 7000

```
diffFormula = "=1-(" & ttlMtrs & "/7000)*1200"
Debug.Print diffForumla
```

I am trying to build a string that will evaluate once printed to a cell in excel.
When I `Debug.print` to check the string I only get blank lines. One time I got long string of garbage characters.

I am trying to figure out what I am misunderstanding in building this string. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: looks to me like 1 left bracket and two right ones.

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you how many times I've recommended Option Explicit this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have mispelled the variable name in the debug statement

```
Debug.Print diffForumla
```

should be

```
Debug.Print diffFormula
```

note the changed position of the `u`

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` in your module will help you avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Thank you, I feel pretty silly. Before it was printing some garbage errors but this is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim ttlMtrs As String
    Dim diffFormula As String
    diffFormula = "=1-(" & ttlMtrs & "/7000)*1200)"
    Debug.Print diffFormula

End Sub
```

This should be the result:

`=1-(/7000)*1200)`

Comment: uneven bracketing.